# DLL inject to another

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dll-injection

I want to be able, to inject my c++ dll into a game, then ask my c# form if a variable if true, then allow the injection, else self destruct or crash the game,

My c# form is a login form with a variable that is true if the person is logged in, but if the dll gets injected into the game, i want it to see the the c# form is logged in, if not then crash the game or self destruct, but i do not want to have the c# form write into a file saying it has logged in, else people could trick my dll, thinking the person has logged in

Comment: What did you try so far? What is the _specific_ problem, you are facing with your attempted solution?

Answer (score -1):

user EsayHook,RemoteInject a dll into remote process,and use ipc share class through IPC channel,check this https://easyhook.github.io/tutorials/remotefilemonitor.html
all in this,wish fo help